# 'Ext.Logger' [undefined] in Phonegap using SenchaTouch for Android

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch-2

I have created my secha touch 2.0 application with google maps in that. When I try to add that  to the phonegap to make android application. I get following error:

```
TypeError: Result of expression 'Ext.Logger' [undefined] is not an object. at file:///android_asset/www/app-all.js:4
```

How can I fix the error?

Comment: hmmm... did you load sencha-touch.js before app-all.js?

Comment: Are you using sencha-touch.js or sencha-touch-debug.js ?

Comment: @TDeBailleul I added both of them. to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the `logger` value in the build options (your app.json file) is set to false:

```
    /**
    * Build options
    */
    "buildOptions": {
        "product": "touch",
        "minVersion": 3,
        "debug": false,
        "logger": false
    },
```

By default the field has the value `'no'` this is a known bug and causes a similar error when publishing a production build.